# React Native TapGestureHandler - how to call a function and send a custom id param

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-animated, react-native-gesture-handler

```
class InfoScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.infoData =[
            {
                id:1,
                title: 'React Native',
                shortDescription: 'Wat is React Native en wat kan het voor u betekenen. Met React Native maken wij moderne apps op maat!',
                color:'green',
            },
            {
                id:2,
                title: 'Magento 2 koppeling',
                shortDescription: 'Een app met een Magento 2 koppeling is mogelijk. Link nu uw Magento 2 webshop met een moderne app!',
                color:'red',
            },
            {
                id:3,
                title: 'Koppeling met API',
                shortDescription: 'Wilt u data vanuit uw systeem in de app zien? Dit is zeker mogelijk zolang er bereik is via een API!',
                color:'blue',
            },
            {
                id:4,
                title: 'Onze waarde',
                shortDescription: 'Wat kan een React Native app voor u betekenen en hoe kunnen wij dit aan u leveren?',
                color:'orange',
            }
        ];

        for(let infoData of this.infoData){
            infoData.borderWidth = 10;
        };
        this.infoData[this.infoData.length - 1].borderWidth = 0;

        this.screenOpacity = new Value(1);

        this.onButtonClicked = event([
            {
                nativeEvent:({state})=>block([
                    cond(eq(state,State.END), set(this.screenOpacity, runTiming(new Clock(), 1, 0)))
                ])
            }
        ]);
    };
    render() { 
    return <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <Animated.View style={{opacity: this.screenOpacity}}>
        <ScrollView>
            {this.infoData.map((data) => {
              return (
                <Animated.View key={data.id} style={{...styles.InfoBlock, backgroundColor:data.color, borderBottomWidth:data.borderWidth}}>
                    <Text style={{...styles.textShadow, textAlign:'center',fontSize:30, color:'white', fontWeight:'bold', marginBottom:20}}>{data.title}</Text>
                    <Text style={{textAlign:'center',color:'white',fontSize:20, marginHorizontal: 20}}>{data.shortDescription}</Text>
                        <TapGestureHandler onHandlerStateChange={this.onButtonClicked}>
                        <Animated.View style={styles.button}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize: 15}}>Bekijk meer</Text>
                        </Animated.View>
                    </TapGestureHandler>
                </Animated.View>
              )
            })}
        </ScrollView>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  };  
}
```

How can I send my data.id to a custom function while also calling the react Animated.Event?
I have created multiple info views and each one has a button to go to the detail page for that info view. Currently, I have no idea how to do this because the onHandlerStateChange calls a react event for animating the screen in. How can I get this data.id from the TapGestureHandler to a function so that I can change the content on the detail screen appropriately?

Comment: Hi @JoostDeVires,
Do you want data.id on onHandlerStateChange={this.onButtonClicked}?
If yes, then you just need to pass the id like this:  <TapGestureHandler onHandlerStateChange={() => this.onButtonClicked(data.id)}>

Comment: If i do that it says this2.onButtonClicked is not a function. Maybe it is possible to call the Animated.Event from a function?

Comment: Yeah i use onHandlerStateChange. have u seen the this.onButtonClick = event([])?

Comment: can you please try with passing data-attribute?

Comment: <TapGestureHandler id={data.id} onHandlerStateChange={this.onButtonClicked}>

Comment: and after i do that how do i get it to a function from the event? i'm sorry im new to react-native.

Comment: This gives me a warning that says invalid prop 'id' of type 'number' supplied to 'TapGestureHandler'

Comment: okay, then remove that id attribute and update your onButtonClicked() and pass id in TapGestureComponent, like below:

onButtonClicked = (event, id) => { 
       event([
            {
                nativeEvent:({state})=>block([
                    cond(eq(state,State.END), set(this.screenOpacity, runTiming(new Clock(), 1, 0)))
                ])
            }
        ])();

     }

<TapGestureHandler onHandlerStateChange={() => this.onButtonClicked(data.id)}>

Comment: Gives an error that says AnimatedEvent is not a function

Comment: Can you please moved onButtonClicked() from the constructor and declare just before render()?

Comment: after declared please update your onButtonClicked() like below:
onButtonClicked = (event, id) => event([
  {
    nativeEvent: ({ state }) => block([
      cond(eq(state, State.END), set(this.screenOpacity, runTiming(new Clock(), 1, 0))),
    ]),
  },
]);

and 

<TapGestureHandler onHandlerStateChange={(event) => this.onButtonClicked(event, data.id)}>

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Animated.call`

```js
this.onButtonClicked = event([
  {
    nativeEvent: ({ state }) =>
      block([
        cond(
          eq(state, State.END),
          set(this.screenOpacity, runTiming(new Clock(), 1, 0))
        ),
        cond(
          eq(state, State.END),
          call([], () => {
            console.log('Something here')
          })
        ),
      ]),
  },
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a inline callback function and which inturns call your actual function with required param.

Here It is.

```
<TapGestureHandler onHandlerStateChange={() => this.onButtonClicked(data.id)}>
```

or

If you need to pass the event as well, then prefer doing this

```
<TapGestureHandler onHandlerStateChange={(event) => this.onButtonClicked(event, data.id)}>
```

Also Make sure, You bind this variable properly inside the constructor function and call Animated.event instead of just event.

```js
class InfoScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.infoData =[
            {
                id:1,
                title: 'React Native',
                shortDescription: 'Wat is React Native en wat kan het voor u betekenen. Met React Native maken wij moderne apps op maat!',
                color:'green',
            },
            {
                id:2,
                title: 'Magento 2 koppeling',
                shortDescription: 'Een app met een Magento 2 koppeling is mogelijk. Link nu uw Magento 2 webshop met een moderne app!',
                color:'red',
            },
            {
                id:3,
                title: 'Koppeling met API',
                shortDescription: 'Wilt u data vanuit uw systeem in de app zien? Dit is zeker mogelijk zolang er bereik is via een API!',
                color:'blue',
            },
            {
                id:4,
                title: 'Onze waarde',
                shortDescription: 'Wat kan een React Native app voor u betekenen en hoe kunnen wij dit aan u leveren?',
                color:'orange',
            }
        ];

        for(let infoData of this.infoData){
            infoData.borderWidth = 10;
        };
        this.infoData[this.infoData.length - 1].borderWidth = 0;

        this.screenOpacity = new Value(1);
        
        // Harding binding with this
        this.onButtonClicked = this.onButtonClicked.bind(this);
    };

    onButtonClicked(event, id) {
        console.log(event, id);
        // try calling with animated.event since the binding is implicit to InfoScreen class
        Animated.event([
            {
                nativeEvent:({state})=>block([
                    cond(eq(state,State.END), set(this.screenOpacity, runTiming(new Clock(), 1, 0)))
                ])
            }
        ])(event); // trigger the function with event passed from the function
    }


    render() { 
    return <View style={{flex:1}}>
      <Animated.View style={{opacity: this.screenOpacity}}>
        <ScrollView>
            {this.infoData.map((data) => {
              return (
                <Animated.View key={data.id} style={{...styles.InfoBlock, backgroundColor:data.color, borderBottomWidth:data.borderWidth}}>
                    <Text style={{...styles.textShadow, textAlign:'center',fontSize:30, color:'white', fontWeight:'bold', marginBottom:20}}>{data.title}</Text>
                    <Text style={{textAlign:'center',color:'white',fontSize:20, marginHorizontal: 20}}>{data.shortDescription}</Text>
                        <TapGestureHandler onHandlerStateChange={(event) =>this.onButtonClicked(event, data.id)}>
                        <Animated.View style={styles.button}>
                            <Text style={{fontSize: 15}}>Bekijk meer</Text>
                        </Animated.View>
                    </TapGestureHandler>
                </Animated.View>
              )
            })}
        </ScrollView>
      </Animated.View>
    </View>
  };  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: If i do that it gives an error that says: this2.onButtonClicked is not a function. Because this.onButtonClicked = Animated.Event. Maybe their is another way to call this Animated.event?

Comment: Please try hard binding `this` with `onButtonClicked` in the constructor function like this

```
this.onButtonClicked  = this.onButtonClicked.bind(this)
```

Comment: i'm sorry i dont see how this is going to solve my problem. it just give me a error which says undefined is not a object.

Comment: Sorry I made mistake, Please move onButtonClicked as a seprate function and call the event inside it, instead of assign it

Comment: it just give me a error which says this.onButtonClicked.bind is not a function

Comment: It does not work, i think the Animated.event can't be used inside a function.

Comment: Animated.event is just a function and returns another function which will be invoked when an event triggers. Also It can be called inside any function. I would suggest to use Animated.event as it is, instead of just calling just `event`. because this context may be lost if you do so. I Guess you need to invoke the function with the `event` as argument. I've updated the code.  could you please try again.

Comment: it gives a error saying AnimatedEvent is not a function

Comment: there is no word which has ` AnimatedEvent` in the code I've shared. Could you please share the entire error message please, that would be helpful along with the line number.

Comment: TypeError: AnimatedEvent is not a function ('near'...}])(evt);...'). their is no line number